# Get text of UILabel after replacing the wrapped text with line break

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

I'm working in an app to draw text on `UIImage`. I display the image on screen and a `UILabel` on it describing the text. User can edit the text. I set `lineBreakMode` to `UILabel` to be `WordWrap`. Now when I get the text to be drawn on the `UIImage` to export it as an Image. The text drawn as one line although it was displayed as multi line on the screen because of the wordwrapping.

Is there a way to replace the wrapped works with linebreak `"\n"`. For example `"Lorem Ipsum"` when I display it in small size label, `"Ipsum"` will be drawn in new line. So I need I call `getText`, I get it as `"Lorem\nIpsum"`

Comment: Please add some code lines on how you extract the text from the lable and turn it into an image.

Comment: If you know how to adapt Objective-C, you can find a working answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235770/uilabel-detect-line-breaks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is the number of lines you have. I had a similar problem before where the words didn't cut off. Add this line of code to your project:

```
label.numberOfLines = 3
```

You can set the number of lines to whatever you need. It should now put each word on a new line. Cheers!