# Get line break in UILabel due to Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, line-breaks

I want to get the text with newline characters as the UILabel is displayed using autolayout on the phone's screen. Thanks.

For example : If I assign

```
label.text = "dhasghdsgah dgahjdg ahjgd hkagkhdhk ajsh djkah"
```

When this is displayed on screen it appears as follows depending on screen width:

```
dhasghdsgah dgahjdg ahjgd

 hkagkhdhk ajsh

  djkah
```

I want to know where the '\n' has been inserted by autolayout.

Kindly correct me if I missed something.

Please find the screenshot :
There is no space in the label.

[image]

Comment: what do you actually want?

Comment: It comes into the next line because the `UILabel` cant fit the whole word in the space available. For example *djkah* won't fit in the second line according to xcode.

Comment: I want to get the text with the newline characters as displayed on UI

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I have to send text to server with details like line change based on the label as displayed on UI.
@Lion

Comment: actually it is vary with device size. If you have ipad then your text will be fit in one line!! so it is not good idea that you send new line character to server! and what is the need of it?

Comment: I have to create a video depending on current screen width . So it is does not matter afterwards as the text will be based on current devices width. Thus i need to replicate the same label on server. Therefore i require the exact text.

Comment: can add screenshot of the label as you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Bilal Please find the screenshot attached

Comment: simple ... it goes to the next line `\n` if word can't fit in the current line. Whats the issue? and as per your screenshots your label looks center justified so it's center justified.

Comment: I want to know when autolayout inserts \n on its own like i m typing without pressing enter so according to bounds autolayout inserts \n automatically. I want to know those \n inserted. @Bilal

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using this method :

```
func getArrayOfStringsOnDifferentLines(label: UILabel) -> [String] {

    let text:NSString = label.text! as NSString
    let font:UIFont = label.font
    let rect:CGRect = label.frame

    let myFont:CTFont = CTFontCreateWithName(font.fontName as CFString, font.pointSize, nil)
    let attStr:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text as String)
    attStr.addAttribute(String(kCTFontAttributeName), value:myFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, attStr.length))
    let frameSetter:CTFramesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attStr as CFAttributedString)
    let path:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(rect.size.width), height: CGFloat(100000)), transform: .identity)

    let frame:CTFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil)
    let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame) as NSArray
    var linesArray = [String]()

    for line in lines {
        let lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line as! CTLine)
        let range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(lineRange.location, lineRange.length)
        let lineString = text.substring(with: range)
        linesArray.append(lineString as String)
    }
    return linesArray
}
```

This method returns an array of string that are on different lines. Now you can use this array as per your need to create a new string with \n join.

My usage :

```
            var stringArray = [String]()

            for newItem in self.getLinesArrayOfStringInLabel(label: item.labelToAdd) {
                stringArray.append(newItem.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ""))
            }
            let stringToSend = stringArray.joined(separator: "\n")
            print(stringToSend)
```

Feel free to ask any detail. Thanks

Comment: So you solved without my help :D, thats why 10+5 points to you.

Comment: LOL , Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code work around for detecting line breaks inside UILabel

```
- (int)getLengthForString:(NSString *)str fromFrame:(CGRect)frame withFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    int length = 1;
    int lastSpace = 1;
    NSString *cutText = [str substringToIndex:length];
    CGSize textSize = [cutText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 500)];
    while (textSize.height <= frame.size.height)
    {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange (length, 1);
        if ([[str substringWithRange:range] isEqualToString:@" "])
        {
            lastSpace = length;
        }
        length++;
        cutText = [str substringToIndex:length];
        textSize = [cutText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 500)];
    }
    return lastSpace;
}


-(NSString*) getLinebreaksWithString:(NSString*)labelText forWidth:(CGFloat)lblWidth forPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    //Create Label
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = labelText;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    //Set frame according to string
    CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(lblWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(point.x , point.y , size.width , size.height)];

    //Add Label in current view
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    //Count the total number of lines for the Label which has NSLineBreakByWordWrapping line break mode
    int numLines = (int)(label.frame.size.height/label.font.leading);

    //Getting and dumping lines from text set on the Label
    NSMutableArray *allLines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    BOOL shouldLoop = YES;
    while (shouldLoop)
    {
        //Getting length of the string from rect with font
        int length = [self getLengthForString:labelText fromFrame:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height/numLines) withFont:label.font] + 1;        

        [allLines addObject:[labelText substringToIndex:length]];

        labelText = [labelText substringFromIndex:length];
        if(labelText.length<length)
            shouldLoop = NO;
    }

    [allLines addObject:labelText];
    //NSLog(@"\n\n%@\n",allLines);

    return [allLines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

**How to use :**

```
NSString *labelText = @"We are what our thoughts have made us; so take care about what you think. Words are secondary. Thoughts live; they travel far.";

NSString *stringWithLineBreakChar = [self getLinebreaksWithString:labelText forWidth:200 forPoint:CGPointMake(15, 15)];
NSLog(@"\n\n%@",stringWithLineBreakChar);
```

You just need to set parameters required by getLinebreaksWithString and you will get a string with each "\n" break included. 
Use your **label width** and starting point you designed in storyboard.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243686/6904341

Comment: Yes i know that. But i need the exact text as it appear on UI with the newline characters so that i can send it to server and it replicates the same thing.

Comment: @Antik Kumar Gupta you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243686/6904341

Comment: Can u please help me with a swift version ?

Comment: I wrote the above in Swift but this truncates after 2 characters and puts a '\n' there. Kindly correct me where I m wrong.

Comment: You didn’t mention language specific and i have given you answer. I did not tried in swift. I think you can accept my answer.

Comment: No probs bro, Thanks for the effort. This didnot work for me actually. I had solved this using CTFrameSetter and related api> Will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for adding a background to a UILabel, but it detects newlines by looking at what point the width of a text exceeds that of the label.

```
-(CAShapeLayer *)backgroundLayerForLabel:(UILabel *)label padding:(float)padding{

    NSString * text = label.text;
    NSArray * words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    UILabel * sizeLabel = [UILabel new];
    sizeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width, 0);
    sizeLabel.font = label.font;
    [sizeLabel setText:@" "]; //just to get row height

    float rowHeight = sizeLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height;
    float runWidth = 0.0f;
    float maxWidth = ceilf(label.frame.size.width);

    float startingX = label.frame.origin.x - padding;
    UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(startingX, label.frame.origin.y)];

    for (NSString * word in words){

        [sizeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", word]];
        float sizeWidth = sizeLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width;

        [sizeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", word]];
        float sizeSpaceWidth = sizeLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width;

        float nextWidth = floorf(sizeWidth + runWidth);
        if (nextWidth > maxWidth){ //spans next line

            [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingX + runWidth + padding, path.currentPoint.y)];
            [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(path.currentPoint.x, path.currentPoint.y + rowHeight)];

            runWidth = sizeSpaceWidth;

        } else {

            runWidth += sizeSpaceWidth;
        }

    }
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingX + runWidth + padding, path.currentPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(path.currentPoint.x, path.currentPoint.y + rowHeight)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingX, path.currentPoint.y)];
    [path closePath];

    CAShapeLayer * layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer.path = path.CGPath;
    layer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    return layer;

}
```

Where nextWidth > maxWidth, that's where your newline kicks in, with the runWidth variable being the length of the sentence. Use like this:

```
    UILabel * label = [UILabel new];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(20, localY, labelWidth, 0);
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0f weight:UIFontWeightSemibold];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = @"This is a really long quotes. I know. a. b. c. defghi. jklmn. op. q. r. stuv. ";
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [label sizeToFit];

    CAShapeLayer * layer = [self backgroundLayerForLabel:label padding:5.0f];
    layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
    [cell.layer addSublayer:layer];
    [cell addSubview:label];
```

Giving you something like this:

[image]